# Total bandwidth limit in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, bandwidth, rate-limiting

The only settings I can find are for limiting in terms of bytes per second but if I understand correctly that'll mean that the connection speed of the site is being throttled as well. What I want to do is to have a hard limit - say 30GB/month, but I don't want to limit the connection speed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option doesn't exist in IIS.  If you had a have a hard limit, you would essentially have the site stop X days into the month once they reached the limit.

To accomplish this, you would need to use an external tool to record the bandwidth per month (whether it's a statistics program, or one that records bandwidth in real-time on the way through).  Then when the limit is reached, use one of the IIS APIs to stop the app pool.

Comment: Thanks! Any recommendations for a program that could do just that?

Comment: I've used Etherpeek in the past for real-time monitoring, although there are likely better applications out there.  Something that runs directly on your network equipment would be ideas for real-time monitoring.  For stats processing, SmarterStats (www.smartertools.com) is a great option.